# Server-side call to FineUploader deleteFile() function returns AWS SignatureDoesNotMatch - 403 error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, delete-file, fine-uploader

My application allows an admin user to build an image gallery by uploading directly to S3 using FineUploader. This processs also stores a document in my local MongoDB db referencing the uploaded image like this...

```
{
   "filename": "user_supplied_image (thumb).jpg",
   "caption": "User supplied caption of image",
   "title": "User supplied title of image",
   "URL_thumb": "http://exnihilodev.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images/risingcrane/d73dbd42-8593-430e-a0f3-bb8512035863.jpg",
   "URL_full": "http://exnihilodev.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images/risingcrane/abf38056-f9f2-4ecb-9f66-c71ca59b3e6f.jpg" 
}
```

This all works just fine. I allow the site administrator to delete any image from the gallery which issues a DELETE request to my server, where the following code is run...

```
// Handler for DELETE /gallery-admin photo delete
app.delete('/gallery-admin', function(req, res) {

    var photo = req.body;
    rcProv.deletePhoto(photo, function(error, docs) {
        if(error) {
            res.send(error);
            console.re.log(error);
        }
        else{
            //1st delete both of the S3 images files associated with this photo
            var key1 = docs.URL_thumb.slice(docs.URL_thumb.indexOf('images/'));
            deleteFile(expectedBucket, key1, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.re.log("Problem deleting file: %s - %s",key1, err);
                    res.status(500);
                }
                res.end();
            });
            var key2 = docs.URL_full.slice(docs.URL_full.indexOf('images/'));;
            deleteFile(expectedBucket, key2, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.re.log("Problem deleting file: %s - %s",key2, err);
                    res.status(500);
                }
                res.end();
            });
            //last, delete the photo record from the db
            photo.remove = true;
            rcProv.deletePhoto(photo, function(error, docs){
                console.re.log('deleted photo successfully: %s',docs);
                res.send({"status":"success"});
            });
        }
    });
});
```

My DELETE route for /gallery-admin calls my internal function 'deletePhoto()', passing in the MongoDb id of the photo which retrieves the document and returns it back in the `docs` var of the callback. This is then parsed to get the filenames of the thumbnail and full image files that were uploaded to S3. These filenames are used to build the keys which are then passed into two subsequent calls to the FineUploader function deleteFile().

The FineUploader deleteFile() functions takes two parameters, `bucket` and `key`, where `bucket` is supplied by the following line of code `var expectedBucket = process.env.S3_BUCKET;` (the same global var being used in other FineUploader functions that are being used during the upload process) and `key` is being supplied with the following line of code...

`var key1 = docs.URL_thumb.slice(docs.URL_thumb.indexOf('images/'));`

...which provides the exact key value passed to the FineUploader signPolicy() function when the file was originally uploaded, basically in the pattern of 'folder/UUID.[file extension]'. I am assuming that this is the 'key' that deleteFile() is looking for. This may be my problem right here.

The response I get back from the S3 server is..

```
{
    "message": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.",
    "code": "SignatureDoesNotMatch",
    "time": "2016-06-16T12:11:47.191Z",
    "statusCode": 403,
    "retryable": false,
    "_willRetry": false
}
```

I've checked my CORS configuration and confirmed that I allow the DELETE method.

I've tried changing the `key` value to various permutations of the original file URL, from a full 'http://...' to just the UUID.[file extension] but with no change in results.

The AWS secret keys used to upload the files are the same keys used to attempt the delete of the same files.

I appreciate any insight into this problem that someone might be able to offer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but this all seems much more complicated than necessary. Why not just pull in the AWS Node.JS SDK and use that to delete your file server-side? If you follow that path, everything should just work, provided you are using the correct keys.

Comment: For reference, see https://github.com/FineUploader/server-examples/blob/master/nodejs/s3/s3handler.js, which is a Node.JS example server that handles all requests from Fine Uploader S3, including a delete file request. It uses the AWS Node.js SDK to delete the file requested by Fine Uploader.

Comment: Ray, that is exactly what I am doing.

I pulled the FineUploader server-side code example from GitHub (years ago) and used it out-of-the-box to handle all server-side processing on my Node.js server.

The only difference is that I am NOT using the FineUploader client-side Delete functionality directly at the time of upload, but rather am calling the same function that the FineUploader Node.js code example uses, just at a later time when the user decides they want to delete an image already uploaded to AWS and in a context divorced from the client-side upload process.

Comment: I guess I'm not seeing why this is tagged fine-uploader or related to fine-uploader then...

Comment: It's tagged fine-uploader because I am using the github server-side example code that is recommended (and written?) by yourself and the whole process is founded upon using the FineUploader product to facilitate the initial file upload to AWS (with related reference files being stored in my local db) which presumably generates the relevant pieces of data that I must now submit to DELETE those same files.

I have been very impressed, thus far, with the FineUploader product as well as it's comprehensive documentation and overall ease of use. Can you help me maintain this level of satisfaction?

Comment: Sorry, handling all support, maintenance, and development of the library ties up enough of my time as it is. I really don't have any spare time to help with matters not directly related to the library.